# How to calculate time differences and average difference in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

The list of dates and times below is pairs of task start and completion times (each successive pair is another task).  I need to know how much time it took to complete each task. Then I want to find the average of how much time it took to complete all 5 tasks.

```
Tuesday, July 21, 2015 4:49:53 PM   
Tuesday, July 21, 2015 4:50:16 PM
Tuesday, July 21, 2015 10:47:16 AM  
Tuesday, July 21, 2015 1:14:58 PM
Tuesday, July 21, 2015 4:50:33 PM   
Tuesday, July 21, 2015 4:57:51 PM
Wednesday, July 29, 2015 4:24:04 PM 
Tuesday, September 01, 2015 3:15:31 PM
Friday, July 03, 2015 2:27:05 PM    
Friday, July 03, 2015 2:31:31 PM
```

How can I do that in Excel 2013?

Comment: You have a list of 10 date/times.  What difference are you trying to calculate (a difference involves two values), and the average of what?

Comment: Sorry it's between 2 sets of dates and time. So if you group them into pairs, it tells me the time I started a task and time I completed the task. I need to know how much time it took to complete. Then an average of how much time it took to complete all 5 tasks

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have ready access to Excel, so I did this in LibreOffice Calc.  Sometimes, functions don't behave exactly alike, so verify that this works for you in Excel.  In LO Calc, this is very straightforward, exactly like you describe as what you want to do:

[image: Screenshot]

In B2, I entered the formula for the first difference: `=A2-A1`

I selected B1 and B2 and copied them down the page.  It produced the series of a blank cell followed by the difference for the associated pair of values in column A.  I just selected a canned cell format to display the difference as hours:minutes:seconds.

LO Calc correctly handles the blank cells when calculating the average.  The formula in B11 is just:  `=AVERAGE(B1:B10)`

If you were running into difficulty, it may have been because of the way Excel stores date/times.  The two are stored together as the number of whole days since a reference date plus the decimal fraction of a day representing the time.  You can do arithmetic with these values.  To get the result to look like a time, you just need to pick a time format and Excel will display it in a familiar form.

If Excel doesn't give you the same result, comment back.